# Unable to migrate data in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

My Django structure follows this article:

[https://studygyaan.com/django/best-practice-to-structure-django-project-directories-and-files#:~:text=The%20way%20I%20like%20to,content%20in%20the%20media%20folder](https://studygyaan.com/django/best-practice-to-structure-django-project-directories-and-files#:%7E:text=The%20way%20I%20like%20to,content%20in%20the%20media%20folder).

where I put my app sync_wits_meta in apps folder
and add app_1 in INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'apps.sync_wits_meta', # <--- here
]
```

then when I run python manage.py makemigrations, it shows the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 210, in create
    app_module = import_module(app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sync_wits_meta'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 420, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 212, in create
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'sync_wits_meta'. Check that 'apps.sync_wits_meta.apps.SyncWitsMetaConfig.name' is correct.
The command '/bin/sh -c python manage.py makemigrations apps/sync_wits_meta' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

How can I do migration if I put app in the apps folder?

I am using Django version 4.1.7.

---

Update：

My project structure is as below:

```
sync_service 
   sync_service
      __init__.py
      asgi.py
      settings.py
      urls.py
      wsgi.py
   apps
      __init__.py
      sync_wits_meta
         __init.py
         admin.py
         apps.py
         models.py
         tests.py
         urls.py
         views.py
   manage.py
   requirement.txt
```

Comment: Can you show your project structure? This question needs more context to be answered

Comment: hi @hassansuhaib , I have updated the post to show my project structure

Answer (score 1):

The `__init.py` is named incorrectly inside `sync_wits_meta`. Change it to `__init__.py`. If that doesn't work here's a longer fix:

Instead of mentioning just the project name, specify a [AppConfig](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig) class for it. In your `INSTALLED_APP` write `apps.sync_wits_meta.apps.SyncWitsMetaConfig` and in your `apps/sync_wits_meta/app.py` add a small class which inherits `AppConfig` class like below:

```py
class SyncWitsMetaConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'sync_wits_meta'
```